# Share extension working on simulator but not on device

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id, slcomposeviewcontroller, ios-extensions

I have a `share-extension` bounded with my app. I have all the required `app-ids` and `provisioning-profiles` related to the extension, for both `development` and `distribution`. When I run the extension in the `simulator`, it works perfectly fine. On `device` (i.e. iPhone 6), for example, when choose my app's `share extension` within `Safari`, `Safari` freezes and nothing opens. I cannot even debug it, not because that I don't know how to do it but because it runs and immediately stops running afterwards on `Xcode`.

I think that something might be wrong with the `provisioning-profiles` or `app-ids` or it might be a bug or a 'missing functionality prior to distribution' caused by `Apple`.

I would very much appreciate it if someone has any solution to or explanation about it.

**EDIT:**

I changed the `background-color` of the extension's view on `storyboard` to see if it does not work at all. It does open, but `SLComposeServiceViewController` did not show up. Thus, the problem must be caused by it.

Comment: Please try to run the extension on a device while plugged into your Mac.  Take a look at the device console and find the relevant error message and update your post.  Most likely it is a provisioning profile / cert issue.  But we'll need to know more if we are to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. It was *not* a provisioning-profile nor an app-id issue. I had written

`override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {}`

method in the `SLComposeServiceViewController` class. It turns out that the only culprit was this method. I removed that and the share extension worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you. It was like a weird bug in my case too. I had made the text view non-editable while sharing. It caused the entire view to be hidden when opening the extension.

Answer (score 7):

If there is anyone still having this issue, please check your Share Extension deployment info and ensure your target OS is lower than your phone's OS[image]

Comment: Worked for me too. The problem is that when adding the new target Xcode defaults to the latest and greatest.